# 'tuple' object is not callable when trying to set permissions for Django Rest API Viewsets

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set up permissions for my User model API. My goal is to let anyone create, list and get users, but only let the user partially update him or herself. However, when I try to make a call to my API i get:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

***views.py***

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def get_permissions(self):
       if self.action == 'partial_update':
           self.permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsUpdateUser,) #Also tried with [isAuthenticated, isUpdateUser], the same goes for the other if statements
       if self.action in ('list','retrieve'):
           self.permission_classes = (SAFE_METHODS,)
       if self.action == 'create':
           self.permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
       return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        serializer = self.UserSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

***permissions.py***

```
class IsUpdateUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # can write custom code
        print (view.kwargs)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(
                pk=view.kwargs['pk'])
        except:
            return False

        if request.user == user:
            return True

        return False
```

The full log for trying to get a user with pk=1

```
Internal Server Error: /users/get-user/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 116, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 401, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 333, in check_permissions
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Desktop\kand\zigma\backend\user\views.py", line 38, in get_permissions
    return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 280, in get_permissions
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
  File "C:\Users\maxso\Envs\zigma_env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 280, in <listcomp>
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
[18/Apr/2019 13:33:45] "GET /users/get-user/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18019
```

Comment: I don't know Django at all, but I think your problem is around this line: `self.permission_classes = (SAFE_METHODS,)` -> Are you sure `SAFE_METHODS` is a valid permission class? The fact that it refers to *methods* in *plural* makes me think this is some kind of collection. In this specific case, a `tuple`.

Comment: Yes, this is very true. Wow, how silly. Thank you!